# comparing CSV files in ubuntu

Tags: bash, csv

I have two CSV files and I need to check for creations, updates and deletions. Take the following example files:

```
ORIGINAL FILE
sku1,A
sku2,B
sku3,C
sku4,D
sku5,E
sku6,F
sku7,G
sku8,H
sku9,I
sku10,J

UPDATED FILE
sku1,A
sku2,B-UPDATED
sku3,C
sku5,E
sku6,F
sku7,G-UPDATED
sku11, CREATED
sku8,H
sku9,I
sku4,D-UPDATED
```

I am using the linux comm command as follows:

```
comm -23 --nocheck-order updated_file.csv original_file > diff_file.csv
```

Which gives me all newly created and updated rows as follows

```
sku2,B-UPDATED
sku7,G-UPDATED
sku11, CREATED
sku4,D-UPDATED
```

Which is great but if you look closely "sku10,J" has been deleted and I'm not sure the best command/way to check for it. The data I have provided is merely demo, the text "sku" does not exist in the real data however column one of the CSV files are a unique 5 character indentifier. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @prime, what you are looking for should be here -> https://www.google.fr/search?q=compare+two+files+with+bash&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=j22OVuzKIcOuPqaRougF

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `join` instead:

```
join -t, -a1 -a2 -eMISSING -o 0,1.2,2.2 <(sort file.orig) <(sort file.update)
```

```
sku1,A,A
sku10,J,MISSING
sku11,MISSING, CREATED
sku2,B,B-UPDATED
sku3,C,C
sku4,D,D-UPDATED
sku5,E,E
sku6,F,F
sku7,G,G-UPDATED
sku8,H,H
sku9,I,I
```

Then I'd pipe that into `awk`

```
join ... | awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    $3 == "MISSING" {print "deleted: " $1,$2; next}
    $2 == "MISSING" {print "added:   " $1,$3; next}
    $2 != $3        {print "updated: " $0}
'
```

```
deleted: sku10,J
added:   sku11, CREATED
updated: sku2,B,B-UPDATED
updated: sku4,D,D-UPDATED
updated: sku7,G,G-UPDATED
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a really crude way of doing it, but if you are certain that the values in each file do not repeat, then:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -u
```

If each file contains repeating strings, then you can `sort|uniq` them before concatenation.